# onClick function only trigger once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched a solution or an answer to get me close to the solution for my problem, without any luck. The problem is that I don't know what is actually causing this.
I have the following HTML sructure :

```
<body>
<div class="showall">
    <div class="comentwrapper" style="height:0; width:800px">

    </div>
    <div class="articol">
        Some article over here !
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="adaugacomentariu" value="Adauga comentariul tau ..." onclick="addBlogComent()" style="float:left; margin-left:5px" /><br /><br />
    <div class="showcomment">
        Coments go over here ..
    </div>
</div>
```

and the follwing JS code :

```
function addBlogComent() {
    $('.comentwrapper').animate({"height":"340px"});
    $('.margine').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
}

function hideComent() {
    $('.margine').fadeOut(200);
    $('.comentwrapper').animate({"height":"0px"});
}

$(function() {
    $('#addblogcoment').on('submit', function(e) {
        $('.aratamesaj').fadeIn(300);

        $.post('submitcomentblog.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            $('.showcoment').load("blogcoment.php");
            $("#addblogcoment").find('input[type=text], textarea').val("");
            $('.aratamesaj').delay(5000).fadeOut(800);
            $('.comentwrapper').delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
        }).error(function() {

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My problem is that after `.post()` and the `.load()` that `.onClick=""` is not animating the form anymore.

I don't understand what can be the cause, because the form and the `button` is on the `.showall` `div` and I'm only `.load()`-ing something in `.showcomment` `div` which is a child of `.showall`.

Maybe someone can see something I'm missing over here .

There is a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZtp8/2/) . Don't have the external resources, but that is not the problem, everything is posted and loaded properly.

You can see the whole page at  [MyWebSite](http://www.pitsol.ro/catalingutu/index.php?page=3) .

Comment: Hi Lucian, to help with your coding and maintenance in years to come, comment is spealt with mm and margin has no e. Hope you don't mind me pointing this out.

Comment: and just another observation: your inconsistent indentation made me actively scan for issues in that regard, the semi-colon terminating functions like statements further threw me off some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your addBlogComent function code as follows, you are animating height but not making element visible.

```
function addBlogComent(){
$('.comentwrapper').css("display","block").animate({"height":"340px"});
    $('.margine').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
};
```

Within your success callback handler fadeOut is setting display none. That is why its only working once. Your onclick function is being called each time. Hope that answer your question.

```
$('.comentwrapper').delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
```

Comment: That works ! Doesn't animate the second time, the form just suddenly appears,but it does the job. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Reset height to 0 after fadeOut, $('.comentwrapper').delay(2000).fadeOut(200,function(){$('.comentwrapper').css('height','0px')});

Comment: That won't work, but I found the way to do it, thank to you. I can do this : $('.comentwrapper').css({"display":"block","height":"0px"}).animate({"height":"340px"});
on addBlogComent() and it will animate the second time as well. 
Thank again, really appreciate .